# perl execute external with space argument

Tags: perl

I have 2 files

```
$file = "songOne.wav";
$file = "song Two.wav";
```

when I execute

```
system("command songOne.wav");
```

It successfully perform the command.

However when I execute

```
system("command song Two.wav");
```

It gives error as there is a space in between,
so the command treats it as 2 arguments,

```
output : 
can't open file song
can't open file Two.wav
```

How do I make make the command treat them as one file?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass [`system`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) a list of arguments:

```
my @args = ("command", "song Two.wav");
system (@args);
```

Or if you don't want to create an array just do:

```
system ("command", "song Two.wav");
```

Comment: there is only one gotcha when passing an array to `system`: should the array contain only one element, that element is subject to shell processing. To force correct interpretation, one can `system {$args[0]} @args`.

Comment: @amon That's interesting.  I hadn't read that in the documentation until now, thanks for the tip.

Comment: ...or use `systemx` from IPC::System::Simple. Bonus: It handles error from the child by throwing an exception.

Comment: @ikegami That's a cool module, hadn't seen it before. BTW feel free to edit.

Comment: @squiguy, It's used by `use autodie qw( system );`

Answer (score 1):

File names that has spaces in it has to be quoted. One of these would do:

```
system("command", "song Two.wav");

system("command \"song Two.wav\"");

system("command 'song Two.wav'");
```